# Looking for Material Implication/XNp/If/then implementation

Tags: php, boolean, truthtable

I'm looking for effective implementation of Material Implication/XNp/If/then for PHP.
Here's example of where I want to use it:

There is collection of object. Each of them has date and type.

I'm writing method that accepts three parameters:

```
function isNewest($obj, $collection, $sameTypeOnly = true){}
```

and check if the `$obj` has newer date (bigger timestamp) than any of objects in `$collection`. I also want to depend my comparison on `$sameTypeOnly` which narrows comparations only to objects of same type.

So far I have:

```
$currentDate = strtotime($obj->getDate());

foreach($relatedObjects as $related){
   if($currentDate < strtotime($related->getDate()) && >>SOMETHING<<){
       return false;
   }
}

return true;
```

There is problem with `SOMETHING`. I want it to check if `$sameTypeOnly` is true, and if it is, check if `$obj->getType() == $related->getType()`.

Of course, I could do that using nested `if()` statements like this:
    $currentDate = strtotime($obj->getDate());

```
foreach($relatedObjects as $related){
   if($sameTypeOnly){
       if($obj->getType() == $related->getType() && $currentDate < strtotime($related->getDate()){
           return false;
       }
   } else {
       if($currentDate < strtotime($related->getDate()){
           return false;
       }
   }
}

return true;
```

and it will work! **BUT IT LOOKS BAD**. I wonder if there is simplier, effective and elegant solution to do this in one if.

After minute of thinking I got my truth table. Assuming that `T` stands for `same type`, `t1 = t2` means that type of first objects matches type of second objects, and `r` is `result`, truth table looks like this:

```
 T | t1 = t2 | r
---|---------|----
 T |    T    | T
---|---------|----
 T |    F    | F
---|---------|----
 F |    T    | T
---|---------|----
 F |    F    | T
```

I looked up for similar table [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Binary_operations), and well, here it is! Column 11 on this table (named "if/then"). I googled for PHP implementation of this operation, with no luck.

Is there any way to implement it using only [operators available in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)? Will it be efficient and fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way and I suppose it will be blazing fast as this is quite simple operation.

```
function implication($p, $q) {
    return !$p | $q;
}
```

You might want to exchange `|` to `||` for your own purposes.

Let's generate truth table for this:

```
$values = array(0,1);

echo "p q r\n";

foreach ($values as $p) {
    foreach($values as $q) {
        echo "$p $q " . implication($p, $q) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
p q r
0 0 1
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 1 1
```

Which is equivalent to truth table you presented.